# Oracle Merge Into (Multiple Joined Tables) Update Set (Multiple Where Statements) Returns Invalid Column Specification

Tags: oracle

I am new to Oracle. I am trying to update the values of a table with the values from a SELECT DISTINCT statement using the MERGE INTO method. I want to update the values for a table based on what is in the USING table conditionally.
A quick diagram of what I am essentially going for is

```
MERGE
INTO update_table ut
USING 
(SELECT DISTINCT
 t1.column_1
,t2.column_2
 FROM table_1 t1
 INNER JOIN table_2 t2
 ON t1.foreign_key = t2.primary_key) st
ON (ut.pk = st.column_1)
WHEN MATCH UPATE
SET(ut.update_column = st.column_2 
    WHERE st.column_1 = 1 
    AND st.column_2 = 1
   ,ut.update_column = st.column_2 
    WHERE st.column_1 = 2 
    AND st.column_2 = 2);
```

However, when I do so I get the INVALID COLUMN SPECIFICATION error on the line where I use SET. How can I work around this to successfully update the table, preferably in ANSI standard?

Answer (score 2):

You can include the conditions that you have added in `where` clause in the selected column list in `using` clause itself. Like This.  (Not tested. Your conditions in `where` clause were not appropriate)

```
MERGE
INTO    update_table ut
USING   (SELECT DISTINCT
                t1.column_1 , 
                CASE 
                        WHEN t1.column_1  = 1 
                                AND t2.column_2 = 1 
                        THEN t2.column_1
                        WHEN t1.column_1 = 2 
                                AND t2.column_2 = 2 
                        THEN t2.column_2
                END column_2
        FROM 
                table_1    t1
        INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.foreign_key = t2.primary_key 
        ) st
ON (ut.pk = st.column_1)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET ut.update_column = st.column_2 ;
```

Comment: Okay so if i understand that correctly that means that I cannot use where statements in this case. I would need to have the correct data set already instead of relying on the where clause in the update statement.

Comment: @Jizzle21013 : you can include where clause for `ut.column_name  = value`  along with the  update if you like. But for source table, it is better you restrict it in the using clause itself.